# Where are the other polynomials without $\alpha$ as a root mapped?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm reading Lang's Undergraduate Algebra, here:

> [image]

Specifically here:

> [image]

I am confused at how the homomorphism ($F[t]\to F(\alpha)$) is defined. It seems that if $\alpha$ is a root of some polinomial $p$, then it is mapped into $0$. But where are the other polinomials mapped? There are polynomials with roots $\beta,\gamma, etc$ and no $\alpha$ root, where are they mapped?

Comment: They are also evaluated at the point $\alpha$. Meaning, if you take a polynomial $f\in F[t]$, then we map this to $f(\alpha)$.

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to write $f\in F[t]$ as $f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^n a_j t^j$ with $a_j \in F$. Then we readily see that $f(\alpha) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \alpha^j$ is an element of $F(\alpha)$ (in fact it would already be an element of $F[\alpha]$).